# Eclipse stops me from adding superfluous tabs

Tags: eclipse

I was editing a fairly extensive ant xml build file file and tried to add in an extra tab where I thought appropriate. As it happens, the tab shouldn't have been there (if we were following some "rules" on What Looks Pretty In XML).

And as it happened, eclipse refused to let me put the tab there. I tried a few times, and sometimes it would "allow" *one* extra tab, but v. often it would either

- ignore the tab
- remove a tab

I know that what eclipse is doing is "right", (in some byzantine sense, because this isn't python, it is an ant xml build file, so the only way it is "right" is from an aesthetics point of view) but I think it is "stupid".

How can i disable this "feature" in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the tabulator key (as opposed to the sub-windows, that are also called tabs).

Look up your editor preferences. Things that might help are the settings "insert spaces for tabs", "displayed tab width" and "smart caret positioning at line start and end".

If this doesn't help, try to avoid the XML editor by not opening with double-click, but using "Open With .." -> "Text Editor"